# Is it possible to make a dataframe of all objects in R?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have loaded a clean workspace in Rstudio and loaded specific objects that I wish to create a dataframe of. So all objects in my workspace are ready to be merged into a master dataframe. When I try to create a dataframe of all the objects using:

```
masterdf<-data.frame(list=ls())
```

I only create a dataframe of the names of the objects, not the values themselves.

Is it possible to create a dataframe that contains all the values? Each object has the same format so there is not a problem with number of columns.

Many thanks.

EDIT: To clarify the question here is an example.

```
x<-c(1,5,7,3,66)
y<-c(3,6,45,78,9)
z<-c(3,8,0,444,34)

masterdf<-data.frame(list=ls())
```

This creates a dataframe of the names of objects, not values themselves i.e.

```
  list
1    x
2    y
3    z
```

What I want is:

```
   x  y   z
1  1  3   3
2  5  6   8
3  7 45   0
4  3 78 444
5 66  9  34
```

Comment: Do you want the objects in the environment to be in the same column? So, is the data.frame going to be long or wide?

Comment: check out the `get` function

Comment: @FrancescoGrossetti It will be long, each object has 7 values and I have 100 objects so there will be 100 rows and 7 columns.

Comment: @bounceyball Thanks, I saw that get() might be the solution but I haven't figured out how to use it yet.

Comment: It is unclear what you want to achieve. Can you report what would be the desired outcome? Why are you talking about values if you said you only need names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `get()` (or the vectorised version `mget()`) to return an object from its name as a string. So to create a data frame from every object in the current environment:

```r
x <- 1:3
y <- 4:6
z <- 7:9

data.frame(mget(ls(), envir = globalenv()))
#>   x y z
#> 1 1 4 7
#> 2 2 5 8
#> 3 3 6 9
```

`envir = global(env)` restricts the search to your user workspace so you don't accidentally include an object from a package with the same name, but I should warn you that this is still an incredibly fragile workflow. I can't really imagine that it would ever make sense to do this as opposed to something like:

```r
data.frame(
  x = 1:3,
  y = 4:6,
  z = 7:9
)
#>   x y z
#> 1 1 4 7
#> 2 2 5 8
#> 3 3 6 9
```

Comment: Thank you I will try this, I have 121 objects, bad planning on my part but I need to create a dataframe of all values now. In the future I will try to concatenate as I generate the objects.

Comment: Suggest `mget` .